# Sending Email in C# from existing table as opposed to a newly created table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is my C# code, it works in that it creates a new table called `Users` and uses the stored procedure to get values from that table, then sends an email to all users in the table. I am new to c# and need to know how to change this code to get data from an "existing" table called `Users`, instead of creating it and getting information from the newly created table.

```
public partial class emailgroup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SendBulkEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Users_GetEmails", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dtUsers);
                    string subject= txtSubject.Text; // Text in Subject
                    string body = txtBody.Text; // Text in Message Body

                    //Using Parallel Multi-Threading send multiple bulk email.
                    Parallel.ForEach(dtUsers.AsEnumerable(), row =>
                    {
                        SendEmail(row["Email"].ToString(), subject, string.Format(body, row["UserName"]));
                    });
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool SendEmail(string recipient, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("gmailusername", recipient); //(put in gmail username between the "")
        mm.Subject = subject;
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = "gmailusername"; //gmailusername (put in "")
        NetworkCred.Password = "gmailpassword"; //gmailpassword (put in "")
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        return true;
    }

    protected void txtBody_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is my stored procedure.

```
-- Users_GetEmails
CREATE PROCEDURE Users_GetEmails

AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT UserName, Email FROM Users
END
```

Comment: Nowhere does any of this code create any new tables... and the newly added code for the stored procedure is getting data from an existing table. What's the problem?

Comment: 'DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();' I presumed from reading on different threads that this created a new temporary table called Users? I think my problem is that I want to select a table instead of creating and using one.

Comment: @OwenFarnan No, this creates a new *instance* of the C# object representing a `DataTable` - which you fill from the already existing actual data table in your database.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You are getting users by way of your stored procedure and storing them in your table instance (da.Fill(dtUsers);). This is exactly what your asking to do. Also try removing the Parallel, in this case you have a very simple operation and the results. Consider making the SendEmail function async.

Comment: I didn't create the Users table before I used this code is why I am confused..

Comment: @OwenFarnan Then create the table in the database. Your code has and should have nothing to do with that. The code assumes the table and connection is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The below doesnt create new users table. It is creating new datatable and fetch info from database via "Users_GetEmails". Then it fills that datatable. You are sending Email with that information from that datatable.

Comment: OK, thank-you. I understand. It is inserting data into the Users table where as I want to pull data from the `Users` table - specifically the `email_address` field so that I can send emails to all values in that column.